# Как подставить ранее загруженные изображения в плагин Fileinput Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, input, fileupload

Реализовал загрузку изображений к карточке товара с помощью данного плагина [Demo](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input).

Плагин на [гите](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/blob/master/js/fileinput.js)

Как можно подставить в поле превью ранее загруженные изображения при редактировании карточки товара, для дальнейшего добавления или удаления изображений?

PHP-Массив изображений с путями и размерами имеется. Как его передать в JS-обработку (мб JSON тип)?

Или направьте на путь истинный пожалуйста...

```
$("#image").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: '#',
    showPreview: true,
    browseOnZoneClick: true,
    browseLabel: 'Выбрать изображения &hellip;',
    removeLabel: 'Очистить',
    removeTitle: 'Удалить все файлы',
    previewFileType: "image",
    allowedFileTypes: ["image"],
    allowedFileExtension: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
    overwriteInitial: false,
    showCaption: false,
    showRemove: true,
    showUpload: false,
    maxFilePreviewSize: 1000,
    maxFileSize: 1000,
    maxFileNum: 15,
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    initialPreview: [
        <?php if (! empty($imgArray)) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($imgArray as $image) : ?>
                '<?= 'http://zend-mvc.loc/'. $image; ?>',
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации плагина установи

```
initialPreview: [
    '<img src="/path_to_file.jpg">',
    '<img src="/path_to_file2.jpg">',
],
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как туда передать PHP-массив с именами файлов?

Comment: Можно пример инициализации?

Comment: Подставить массив с названиями получилось, фото отображаются. Но выходит не туда копал. Нужно чтобы можно было их редактировать как при новой загрузке, чтобы они были такими же объектами при редактировании.

Comment: При создании продукта, можно загружать в область preview файлы, а затем удалять ненужные и снова добавлять до отправки на сервер.

Comment: Для каждого элемента пишется конфиг:
initialPreviewConfig: [
    {
        caption: 'desert.jpg',
        width: '120px',
        url: '/localhost/avatar/delete',
        key: 100,
    },
    {
        caption: 'jellyfish.jpg', 
        width: '120px', 
        url: '/localhost/avatar/delete', 
        key: 101, 
    }
]

url: ссылка на удаление картинки через AJAX
key: id который отправится постом через AJAX

Comment: Это понятно, но удаление из превью не должно удалять с сервера. В превью картинки как бы подготавливаются, а летят на сервер без использования AJAX. Ведь при создании нового продукта и загрузки картинок, картинки отобразившиеся в превью еще не на сервере же. Насколько я понимаю они в памяти браузера?

Comment: Так как Вы ответили на поставленный вопрос - отмечу как правильный. Проблема не решена - но это уже следующая задача!